# Why is my AngularJS variable being passed as the literal code?

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying to pass a variable to a function in my javascript.  When I look at the button in the developer tools, the variable is set to the value that I expect, the name of the file.  If I set a breakpoint in the javascript and look at the attachmentName variable that looks fine in the developer tools for the HTML, it comes out as {{vm.requisition.pOR_Detail.attachment_Name}} instead of the name of the file.  What can I do to pass the correct value?

**HTML**

```
<button class="col-xs-3" class="btn btn-default"
        data-ng-show="vm.requisition.requisitioner === vm.currentUser.username"
        data-ng-click="deleteAttachment('{{vm.requisition.pOR_Detail.attachment_Name}}')"
        type="button">Remove Attachment</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$scope.deleteAttachment = function (attachmentName) {
    Upload.upload({
        url: '../../DeleteHandler.ashx',
            data: { attachmentName: attachmentName }
        }).then(function (resp) {
            console.log('File deleted. Response: ' + resp.data);
        }, function (resp) {
            console.log('Error status: ' + resp.status);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

drop the interpolation and quotes from function call

```
<button data-ng-click="deleteAttachment(vm.requisition.pOR_Detail.attachment_Name)" type="button">Remove Attachment</button>
```